# jQuery ignoring status code from Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, express

I'm making an application where a form has to be validated with AJAX. Nothing too fancy. When a form submit is triggered I'm posting to a URL on a Node.js server and routing with Express. If the data does not pass all of the validation requirements, I'm sending a status code of 400, like so:

```
app.post('/create', checkAuth, function (req,res)
{
    var errors = new Errors();

    if (req.body['game-name'].length < 3 || req.body['game-name'].length > 15)
    {
        res.send({
            msg: 'Game name must be between 3 and 15 characters.'
        }).status(500).end();
    }
    else
    {
        GameModel.find({id: req.body.roomname}, function (err,result)
        {
            if (result.length !== 0)
            {
                errors.add('A game with that name already exists.');
            }

            //Some more validation

            if (errors.get().length > 0)
            {
                res.status(400).send({
                    msg: errors.get()[0]
                }).end();

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var data = new GameModel({
                    roomname: req.body['roomname'],
                    owner: req.session.user,
                    id: req.body['roomname'].toLowerCase(),
                    config: {
                        rounds: req.body['rounds'],
                        timeLimit: req.body['time-limit'],
                        password: req.body['password'],
                        maxplayers: req.body['players'],
                        words: words
                    },
                    finished: false,
                    members:
                    [
                        req.session.user
                    ]
                });

                data.save(function (err, game)
                {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.send({
                            msg: 'Something funky happened with our servers.'
                        }).status(500).end();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.send({
                            msg: 'All good!'
                        }).status(200).end();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On the client side, I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/someURL",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    statusCode:
    {
        200: function (data)
        {
            //All good.
        },
        400: function (data)
        {
            //Uh oh, an error.
        }
    }
});
```

Strangely, jQuery is calling the 200 function whenever I send a 400 error. I believe this is because I'm sending an object along with the status code. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you run this with the browser developer tools "network" tab open and include a screenshot of this specific HTTP request showing the full response headers and body? I suspect the response is different than you expect due to an express routing issue.

Comment: Oh, also show the full server snippet. You are missing a `return;` statement inside that `if` block. I bet your code is falling through and changing the status and body because both the error code and the success code are running.

Comment: The server code is quite extensive but I'll update and abbreviate it. The Chrome network tab is indeed showing a 200, so I guess it isn't jQuery's problem.

Comment: Yes, put some `console.log` in your express code to be 100% certain the code you think is responding is actually responding, and what the response body looks like. Almost certainly a routing issue or a control flow error.

Comment: I know for a fact that the 400 line is being run because it's the only one that sends a response with the error message and based on client side logging I'm getting the message, just not the status code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First guess is you need a `return;` statement in your express code inside that `if` block. I bet the error code is running then the success code and the last values for the statusCode/body are being sent to the browser.

Comment: You were right. As you can see in the updated code the first error handled before the mongoose callback sends the status after the message, apparently sending a 200.